# Printing within list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list, function, printing, list-comprehension

I am getting a syntax error when executing the following code. 
I want to print within a list comprehension. 
As you see, I tried a different approach (commented out line) by using print(). But I think this syntax is supported in Python 3 as earlier versions of Python treat print as a statement.

```
  1 import sys
  2 import nltk
  3 import csv
  4 from prettytable import PrettyTable
  5 CSV_FILE = sys.argv[1]
  6 # Handle any known abbreviations, # strip off common suffixes, etc.
  7 transforms = [(', Inc.', ''), (', Inc', ''), (', LLC', ''), (', LLP', '')]
  8 csvReader = csv.DictReader(open(CSV_FILE), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
  9 contacts = [row for row in csvReader]
 10 companies = [c['Company'].strip() for c in contacts if c['Company'].strip() != '']
 11 for i in range(len(companies)):
 12     for transform in transforms:
 13         companies[i] = companies[i].replace(*transform)
 14 #fields=['Company', 'Freq']
 15 #pt = PrettyTable(fields=fields)
 16 #pt.set_field_align('Company', 'l')
 17 fdist = nltk.FreqDist(companies)
 18 #[pt.add_row([company, freq]) for (company, freq) in fdist.items() if freq > 1] 
 19 #[print("["+company+","+freq+"]") for (company, freq) in fdist.items() if freq > 1] 
 20 [print company for (company, freq) in fdist.items() if freq > 1]
 21 #pt.printt()
~
```

Comment: "I want to print within a list comprehension."  Why?  The point of a list comprehension is to build a list.  If you're just going to throw the list away, why not simply use a `for` loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No** statements can appear in Python expressions.  `print` is one kind of statement in Python 2, and list comprehensions are one kind of expression.  Impossible.  Neither can you, for example, put a `global` statement in an index expression.

Note that in Python 2, you can put

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

to have `print()` treated as a function instead (as it is in Python 3).

Answer (score 12):

It's not a print statement in Python 3, it's a function.

```
>>> sys.version
'3.4.0a4+ (default:8af2dc11464f, Nov 12 2013, 22:38:21) \n[GCC 4.7.3]'
>>> [print(i) for i in range(4)]
0
1
2
3
```

and returns:

```
[None, None, None, None]
```

And as Tim Peters said, no statements can be in comprehensions or generator expressions.

Answer (score 5):

The other answer is: Don't do this. Use a `for` loop. There's no need to materialize a list of `None`'s in memory. The print function returns None, and the printing is a mere side-effect from the perspective of functional programming. If you need the printing, use a for-loop, since there's no need to materialize a list in memory. If you need the list of `None`'s, use `None`, not `print(i)`, since this would make your program IO bound.

If you need both, do them so that you can easily remove the one you don't need when you are done.

Comment: Add this to your other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20296330/2142994) and it would be a good answer.