# for loop with print in functional programming style python

Tags: python, for-loop, functional-programming

How can I change the following program in Python to functional style?

```
from itertools import permutations
for p in permutations(range(1, int(input()) + 1)):
    print(*p, sep='')
```

I know about map, but

```
map(lambda p: print(*p, sep=''), permutations(range(1, int(input()) + 1)))
```

doesn't produce the expected output.

I wonder if it is possible to do so without 'redefining' the for loop.

Comment: What benefit do you gain from this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20296780/2308683 (and other answers there)

Comment: this is an exercise in one of my courses, and for is not allowed there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` should not be used for **side-effects** functions.
The `print` function is returning `None` so you are building a list (or generator in python3) that will contain as many Nones as items in the collection you are iterating, completly useless.
You can use a `while` loop:

```
def printFrom(col):
    i = iter(col)
    while True:
        try:
            print(next(i))
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

As functional style, you can use `recursion`:

```
def printFrom(col):
    it = iter(col)
    def printit(i):
        try:
            print(next(i))
            printit(i)
        except StopIteration:
            return
    printit(it)
```

Or also just this:

```
print(" ".join(map(lambda x: " ".join(map(str, x)),permutations(range(1, 10)))))
```

The idea of this last solutions is that you build the actual final string before printing it with just one call.

Comment: Furthermore, in python 3, `map` returns a lazy iterator. So the print function is not evaluated until you actually loop over the resulting `map`. This can be done using `str.join(map(...))` or `list(map(...))`.

Comment: @HåkenLid, you should not call `print` whithing `map` in `list(map(...))` , you will end up building a fully uselss list.

Comment: Yes, but the OP asks why the code didn't produce any results. It might not be obvious why nothing is printed to stdout. The reason is that `map` is lazy. I'm not saying that it's a good practice to map over functions that has side effects.

Comment: @HåkenLid yeah, absolutly, that  is why i just pointed out that consumiing the map with a list it is not a good idea, i wasnt saying the other message wasnt wrong, sorry if i did not explain myself properly.